# POST data not passed in to $.ajax({ }

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm building a search box. It seems that the search text is not passing in to $.ajax({

`alert(val1);` works but `alert("step4 - working");` is not showing. How can this be fixed?

```
<div class="imageSlots" id="imageSlots"></div>
<form action="" method="post">
        Search Word:         
         <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1" />
         <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn" />
        </form>
      </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var val1 = $('#val1').val();
        $('#btn').click(function(e) {       
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(val1);
            $.ajax({
            alert("step4 - working");                   
                url: 'php/file1.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'val1':val1},

                success: function(data, status) {
                    $("#imageSlots").html(data);

                }
            });
            $("#imageSlots").fadeOut("slow");
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You can't just paste an function call (`alert()`) in the middle of an object declaration (`{...}`). To debug your ajax calls open up your network tab or use a HTTP sniffer such as Fiddler2.

Comment: Paste it into `success` and it will show up when it actually success.

Comment: use browser console to look for errors. You would see one as soons as this code loads

Comment: I used `console.log ();` above `$.ajax({`

Comment: @user3687622 You're welcome. If you want to output an alert after returning (even on errors such as 404 etc.), simply add a `complete: function() { alert('we got an answer'); }` key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code to following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var val1 = $('#val1').val();
        $('#btn').click(function(e) {       
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(val1);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'php/file1.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'val1':val1},                    
            success: function(data, status) {
                    alert("step4 - working");  
                    $("#imageSlots").html(data);

                }
            });
            $("#imageSlots").fadeOut("slow");
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks cpoDesign :) that worked! So it confirms that the POST is passed on successfully. But why isn't php reading the data? `if( isset($_POST['val1']) ){`

Comment: put breakpoint before alert, in your javascript  or use fiddler, what is response or better show us example of the result what is passed back.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. You can't place an `alert` inside an object literal. Move it above.

Comment: thanks. How do I check if the text is being passed in to `$.ajax({` ?

Comment: @user3687622 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
Also, please accept if this solved your problem. :)